# ASP.NET MVC and jQuery - Problem with ajax encoding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I'm using this to save some data to DB:

```
$("#btnSave").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        data: 'description=' + oEditor.GetXHTML(),
        url: '/SuperAdmin/ReceiveData/',
        success: function () {
            alert('news saved');
        }
    });
});
```

"oEditor.GetXHTML" is taken from FCKEditor. 
And, to receive this data I have a ASP.NET MVC method (ActionResult):

```
public void ReceiveData(string description)
{
}
```

The point is: when I send, for example, this sentence **include the "JavaScript Integration Module" scripts**, the ReceiveData method only gets until **include the** ... what comes after that doesn't come.

Debugging my jQuery function above, I saw that the sentence that I'm trying to pass to the method has HTML encoding with &, amp; and so on. And the double quotes of the **..."JavaScript Integration Module"...** is being interpreted by the ReceiveData method as a parameter, because the double quotes have the '&' in it encoding.

So, how can I transform this '& quote' to " before send to the MVC method? Or is there a way to make this method recognize this '& quote' as a character and not a parameter?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `escape(oEditor.GetXHTML())`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Predefined_Functions/Escape_and_unescape_Functions